# Styling Subsequent Pages in Craft Pagination

Tags: craft3

I am building my first Craft blog, and can't figure out how to get the CSS styling to apply to pagination beyond the main blog index page. When I click through subsequent blog pages, the URL adds 'p2', 'p3', etc. as expected, and all of the HTML content and links are there and work fine. But no styling beyond the first page. Any ideas? Here is my pagination code in my main blog index.html:

```
{# Pagination and home page link #}
<div class="blog-nav">
    {% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}
        <a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}" class="blog-nav-link">Prev</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}
        <a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}" class="blog-nav-link">Next</a>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="../index.html" class="blog-nav-link">Home</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who might stumble upon this with a similar issue, the answer ended up being quite simple...

I made sure that my css.main was located in a public directory, in my case /web/css/main.css, and all of the pagination and styling works perfectly.